# java interface and child class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I have the next question. I have interface

```
public interface MyInterface {
    blah blah
}
```

And I have child:

```
public class MyChild implemets MyInterface {
    blah blah
}
```

What is the difference between:

```
MyChild child = new MyChild();
```

and

```
MyInterface child = new MyChild();
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Your added code snippet is -

```
MyChild child = new MyChild();
```

and

```
MyInterface child = new MyChild();
```

In first case `child` can contain only the object of `MyChild` class. But in the second case `child` (where child is a `MyInterface`) can contain all object of those class that implements `MyInterface`. Here you can get the advantage of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
MyInterface child = new MyChild();
```

you are doing what is called "coding to an interface" and it allows you to respect the Open Closed Principle: Open for extension but closed for modification. This allows you to leverage dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Creating an instance of a class has nothing to do with the _open/closed principle_ this is a matter of design.

Comment: @tomse, of course it is. Don't try to find problems where they don't exist. I had to paste that bit of the post to illustrate which statement adhered to coding to an interface. The fact that it is a object creation statement is by the by!

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood your intention a bit since the _open/closed principle_ is nothing the user of a class should have to take care about, instead the creator of a class should ensure that its implementation of an interface is in line with this principle. So for this question the _open/closed principle_ is not relevant and IMO more confusing than helpful...